# How to get the Features of FeatureCursor?

Tags: arcgis-10.2, arcobjects, vba

I am unsure how to correctly use `IFeatureCursor.NextFeature` method.

I've selected a few features:

[image]

I need to assigne the selected features into few `pFeature` variables (`pFeature1`, `pFeature2`, `pFeature3`)

The code below seems to be the solution, but it doesnt.

```
Dim pMxDoc As IMxDocument
Dim pFeatureLayer As IFeatureSelection
Dim pFeatureSelection As ISelectionSet
Dim pFeatureCursor1 As IFeatureCursor

Dim pFeature1 As IFeature
Dim pFeature2 As IFeature
Dim pFeature3 As IFeature

Set pMxDoc = ThisDocument
Set pFeatureLayer = pMxDoc.FocusMap.Layer(0)
Set pFeatureSelection = pFeatureLayer.SelectionSet

pFeatureSelection.Search Nothing, True, pFeatureCursor1

Set pFeature1 = pFeatureCursor1.NextFeature
Set pFeature2 = pFeatureCursor1.NextFeature
Set pFeature3 = pFeatureCursor1.NextFeature

MsgBox pFeature1.Value(2) & pFeature2.Value(2) & pFeature3.Value(2)
```

To check the result I used a MsgBox containing the value of `"NAME_MST"` field.

[image]

I can't explain it, but every `PFeature` contains the last Feature of `pFeatureCursor`.

To solve this problem I have to write a preposterous code as shown below (by using a few `pFeatureCursors`).

```
Dim pMxDoc As IMxDocument
Dim pFeatureLayer As IFeatureSelection
Dim pFeatureSelection As ISelectionSet
Dim pFeatureCursor1 As IFeatureCursor
Dim pFeatureCursor2 As IFeatureCursor
Dim pFeatureCursor3 As IFeatureCursor

Dim pFeature1 As IFeature
Dim pFeature2 As IFeature
Dim pFeature3 As IFeature


Set pMxDoc = ThisDocument
Set pFeatureLayer = pMxDoc.FocusMap.Layer(0)
Set pFeatureSelection = pFeatureLayer.SelectionSet

pFeatureSelection.Search Nothing, True, pFeatureCursor1
pFeatureSelection.Search Nothing, True, pFeatureCursor2
pFeatureSelection.Search Nothing, True, pFeatureCursor3

Set pFeature1 = pFeatureCursor1.NextFeature

Set pFeature2 = pFeatureCursor2.NextFeature
Set pFeature2 = pFeatureCursor2.NextFeature

Set pFeature3 = pFeatureCursor3.NextFeature
Set pFeature3 = pFeatureCursor3.NextFeature
Set pFeature3 = pFeatureCursor3.NextFeature

MsgBox pFeature1.Value(2) & pFeature2.Value(2) & pFeature3.Value(2)
```

[image]

The result is correct but I don't like the way I've reached it. What do I do wrong in first code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The naming convention you have used is not good, you declare `pFeatureLayer`, which to everyone on the planet should be an `IFeatureLayer` object, but you have declared it as an `IFeatureSelection`. Therefore it is *very* difficult for anyone including you to follow what the code is actually referencing. Get into the habit of declaring objects as they should be and then cast them into other interfaces (I think this is called Query Interface).

I have rewritten your code into a much easier to follow code.

Now the reason why your first attempt failed was the type of cursor you were returning from the SelectionSet (which you were calling `pFeatureSelection`). You had the recycling parameter set to True, so all I did was set it to False and the code behaves in the manner you were expecting.

```vb
Public Sub SearchSelection()

    Dim pMxDoc As IMxDocument
    Dim pFeatureLayer As IFeatureLayer
    Dim pFeatureSelection As IFeatureSelection
    Dim pSelectionSet As ISelectionSet
    Dim pFeatureCursor As IFeatureCursor
    Dim pFeature1 As IFeature
    Dim pFeature2 As IFeature
    Dim pFeature3 As IFeature

    Set pMxDoc = ThisDocument
    Set pFeatureLayer = pMxDoc.FocusMap.Layer(0)
    Set pFeatureSelection = pFeatureLayer
    Set pSelectionSet = pFeatureSelection.SelectionSet

    pSelectionSet.Search Nothing, False, pFeatureCursor

    Set pFeature1 = pFeatureCursor.NextFeature
    Set pFeature2 = pFeatureCursor.NextFeature
    Set pFeature3 = pFeatureCursor.NextFeature

    MsgBox pFeature1.Value(2) & pFeature2.Value(2) & pFeature3.Value(2)
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

> ...you declare `pFeatureLayer`, which to everyone on the planet should be
>   an `IFeatureLayer` object, but you have declared it as an
>   `IFeatureSelection`...

@Hornbydd, I've repeated that mistake after example (below) at my arcobjects cookbook (Programming ArcObjects with VBA Second Edition). I noticed that variance (`pFeatureLayer` -  `IFeatureSelection`) but I was sure it's normal.

It's funny - the code works correct for my purpose even keeping that string `Dim pCountyLayer As IFeatureSelection` . Setting the recycling parameter to False was enough.

Many thanks for your help!!!

```
' Part 1: Define the selected feature on the layer for selection.
Dim pMxDoc As IMxDocument
Dim pCountyLayer As IFeatureSelection
Dim pCountySelection As ISelectionSet
Dim pCountyCursor As IFeatureCursor
Dim pCounty As IFeature
Set pMxDoc = ThisDocument
Set pCountyLayer = pMxDoc.FocusMap.Layer(1)
Set pCountySelection = pCountyLayer.SelectionSet
' Create a cursor from the selected feature in Layer (1).
pCountySelection.Search Nothing, True, pCountyCursor
' Return the selected feature from the cursor.
Set pCounty = pCountyCursor.NextFeature
```